# How to configure spotless google formatter to format braces

Tags: java, spotless

How to configure spotless google formatter to format braces in 2 lines instead of a single line

```
-    void contextLoads() {}
+    void contextLoads() {
+    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. From `google-java-format`'s [README](https://github.com/google/google-java-format):

> Note: There is no configurability as to the formatter's algorithm for formatting. This is a deliberate design decision to unify our code formatting on a single format.